# Facebook like button, adjusting the "Share it on facebook with a comment..." popup

Tags: facebook

Hey, I'm just wondering if there is a way to modify the popup that appears after you've hit the 'like' button.

Right now, it appears to the right of the like button.. Problem is, the button is to the very right of the page, so it bleeds off..  Is there a way to customize the positioning of this box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only move the popup with CSS, you can't apply styles to the content of the iFrame.

If you have the like button too close to right you can use this:

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
    top: -150px !important;
    left: -150px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrow's problem is that it's inside an iframe, so you can't apply css to it.
I hope facebook will provide a way to customize all theres widgets.